# Read out error from meta file/meta data in error message

Tags: java, c#, console, metadata

I was wondering how I could read out errors from a meta file. Lets say I have a large XML or JSON File with 300 entries. And maybe a key or a name might be spelled wrong. 
Yeah I know, if I'm gonna parse it to an language and it isn't correct, an exception will be thrown. 
But how could I just give system prints (Like Console.writeline()) like that "There occured an error on entry 100 in line 45 for wrong spelled word "appel".
Do you have any ideas how to fix it? All I want to have is a nice readable error message, where exactly in the file (not in the IDE) the mistake occured.

Comment: Is your question about java or c#?

Comment: It's about Java